# Appending objects to list results in a list of the last object only

Tags: python

I'm trying to take a dataframe and create a class instance for each row. When I append these objects to a list, only the last object is being appended. I can't determine where I'm making the mistake.

### My code

```py
import pandas as pd

df_dict = pd.read_excel(excel_path).to_dict("records")    
xl_field_list = []
for field in df_dict:
    xl_field = XLField(
    field1=field["Field 1"],
    field2=field["Field 2"],
    field3=field["Field 3"],
    field4=field["Field 4"],
    )
    xl_field_list.append(xl_field)

for f in xl_field_list:
    print(f.field1)
```

### Result

```
0052
0052
0052
0052
0052
0052
```

If I add a `print(xl_field.field1)`before `xl_field_list.append(xl_field)`, I get the expected results.

### Code for XLField class

I've added the code for the XLField class as has been requested.

```py
class XLField1:
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        value = value.upper()
        if not re.fullmatch(r"[A-Z0-9]{2}", value):
            raise ValueError("Check Field 1")
        self.value = value


class XLField2:
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, obj, value):

        value = str(value).zfill(4)
        if not re.fullmatch(r"[0-9]{3,4}", value):
            raise ValueError("Check Field 2")
        self.value = value


class XLField3:
    Days_Of_The_Week = [
        "MONDAY",
        "TUESDAY",
        "WEDNESDAY",
    ]

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        value = value.upper()
        if value not in XLField3.Days_Of_The_Week:
            raise ValueError("Check Field 3")
        self.value = value


class XLField4:
    INT_OR_COM = ["A", "D"]

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        value = value.upper()
        if value not in XLField4.INT_OR_COM:
            raise ValueError("Check Field 4")
        self.value = value


class XLField:
    field1 = XLField1()
    field2 = XLField2()
    field3 = XLField3()
    field4 = XLField4()

    def __init__(self, field1, field2, field3, field4):
        self.field1 = field1
        self.field2 = field2
        self.field3 = field3
        self.field4 = field4
```

---

Please let me know if there is anything else that I should include.

Comment: There must be something ridiculous going on in the `XLField` constructor. But as of right now, we can't reproduce this locally, since the code is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If I write an `XLField` class that works sanely and does what I intuitively expect, then I won't see the problem you're describing.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Can you provide the code of `XLField` class?

Comment: Remove the first four lines from the `XLField` class. Those are class attributes, not instance attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your class attributes with each iteration as you defined your class XLField with class attributes and you overwrite them in your __init__ method. That is why only the last values remain for **all** instances of the class.

```
class XLField:
    field1 = XLField1()
    field2 = XLField2()
    field3 = XLField3()
    field4 = XLField4()

def __init__(self, field1, field2, field3, field4):
    self.field1 = field1
    self.field2 = field2
    self.field3 = field3
    self.field4 = field4
```

I would suggest a probably more pythonic approach: implement __init__ methods in your Field classes where you make the checks you are currently doing in your __set__ methods, and instantiate them in the constructor:

```
class XLField:

    def __init__(self, field1, field2, field3, field4):
        self.field1 = XLField1(field1)
        self.field2 = XLField2(field2)
        self.field3 = XLField3(field3)
        self.field4 = XLField4(field4)
```